# How to search and fetch a Message using gmail Hex messageId in java-gmail-imap api

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail, imap

I have a Gmail message id (hex String) '149e841b6e3b1bfa' and I need to search and fetch this email using java-gmail-imap api. I could not find a way to do this however. The google developer page [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions#access_to_the_gmail_unique_message_id_x-gm-msgid) says this.

I ended up fetching all the X_GM_MSGID from Inbox and compare each message's GoogleMessageId with message Id I have. Code below:

```
MyImapUtil imapUtil = new MyImapUtil();
com.google.code.javax.mail.Message[] ms;
com.google.code.com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore store = imapUtil.connectToGmailImap(userGuid);
folder = (com.google.code.com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("INBOX");
/*folder = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("[Gmail]/Starred");
folder1 = (IMAPFolder) store1.getFolder("[Gmail]/All Mail");*/
if (folder != null && !folder.isOpen()) {
    folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
}

//List<EmailThread> emailThreads = (List<EmailThread>) folder.doCommand(new SearchUnreadThreads(andTerm));

ms = folder.getMessages();
com.google.code.javax.mail.FetchProfile fp = new com.google.code.javax.mail.FetchProfile();
fp.add(com.google.code.com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.FetchProfileItem.X_GM_MSGID);

folder.fetch(ms, fp);

long messageIdLong=-1;
try {
    messageIdLong = Long.parseLong(messageIdHex,16);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if(messageIdLong==-1)
    return false;   // Not able to Parse the gmail hex messageID for the message
IMAPMessage im;
for (int i = ms.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        im = (IMAPMessage) ms[i];
        if(messageIdLong == im.getGoogleMessageId()){
            // DO WHAT YOU WANT WITH THIS MESSAGE HERE
            return true;
        }

}
```

As you can see, this is not elegant as I have to fetch all the Inbox emails in order to find 1 email. Also it is not guaranteed that my email is in Inbox only, so I will have to search in All Mails. Can you suggest a better way to search my desired mail based on Gmail Message Id(X_GM_MSGID). Please note I don't want to use plain vanilla JavaMail or google mail API.

Comment: You need to send a `UID SEARCH` by `X-GM-MSGID` to get the `UID`, then send a `UID FETCH`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert 149e841b6e3b1bfa to decimal, then issue `UID SEARCH X-GM-MSGID 423789473343342289423` (or whatever the number is).

Comment: Oh. I didn't notice the comment that says the same thing. Too early in the morning for me.